# Elastic search grouping unique values

Tags: elasticsearch, group-by, distinct

I have some data:

```js
[{
    "article_id": 257710962,
    "category_id": "category1"
},
{
    "article_id": 257710962,
    "category_id": "category2"
},
{
    "article_id": 257713968,
    "category_id": "category3"
},
{
    "article_id": 257717376,
    "category_id": "category4"
}]
```

How should I make a query for getting a result like this

```js
[{
    "article_id": 257710962,
    "category_id": ["category1", "category2"]
},
{
    "article_id": 257713968,
    "category_id": "category3"
},
{
    "article_id": 257717376,
    "category_id": "category4"
}]
```

I need to do that query because i'm using pagination on my page. So, it's a must to prevent duplication. ***(I'm using the article_id as my primary key)***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your each document source is like this

```
"_source": {
               "article_id": 257710962,
               "category_id": "category2"
            }
```

then you can try **Terms Aggregation** with **Top hits Aggregation**

```
GET /my_index/my_type/_search
{
   "size": 0,
   "aggs": {
      "agg1": {
         "terms": {
            "field": "article_id"
         },
         "aggs": {
            "agg2": {
               "top_hits": {}
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

for further clarification: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-top-hits-aggregation.html

Comment: how about the "from" key? for pagination

Comment: I don't think in case of aggregation _'from'_ key will work.
you need to guess reliable size of total number of expected result, then pass _'size'_ parameter in terms array
[https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation-approximate-counts]